# assigning a MUI component in a variable, and using it later, in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to store an MUI component, more specifically an MUI icon, in a variable, something like

```
item.icon = <FilterListIcon />;
```

And later, in other components, doing:

```
<ListItem button key={item.text} onClick={item.onClick}>
    {item.icon &&
        {
            <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon> 
        }}
    <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
</ListItem>
```

But, when I do so, the browser page gets empty, everything disappears

I'm doing the same with the name and other stuff, but it works:

```
item.text = 'Item 1 for spv';
item.onClick = () => navigate('/showPlainVideos');
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function App() {
  const someInstances = [
    <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>,
    <Button variant="contained">Hello1 World</Button>,
    <Button variant="contained">Hello2 World</Button>
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{someInstances}</div>
      {/*do some processing if you want*/}
      <div>{someInstances.map((ins) => ins)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-flower-v1dsy?file=/src/App.js:0-437

Comment: Yes, in one place I do "newMenuItem.icon = <FilterListIcon />;" and in other place I do "<ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>", I the browser page gets blank

Comment: @Rafael can you share more of your code, in a codesandbox,.io so it will be easier for me to get it??

Comment: Ok, I'll try, I'm using redux and other stuff, so I have to make a little project for that, I'll do it

Comment: Thank you for answering @Maifee Ul Asad, the problem was stupid, I was typing import {FilterListIcon} from '@mui/icons-material/FilterList'; instead of 'import FilterListIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterList';'

Comment: okay... if it helped, maybe you can accept it and try upvoting...